# rake db:migrate Error 1064 Lynda.com Ruby on Rails 4 Issue

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

```
class CreateUsers < ActiveRecord::Migration

def up
create_table :users do |t|
  t.column "first_name", :string, :limit => 25
  t.string "last_name", :limit => 50
  t.string "email", :default => "", :null => false
  t.string "password", :limit => 40
  t.timestamps
end
end

def down
  drop_table :users
end

end
```

I'm attempting to run rake db:migration and I'm getting

```
mysql> rake db:migration;
```

ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'rake db:migration' at line 1

Answer (score 1):

```
t.string "email", :default => "" :null => false
```

You're missing a comma between your arguments to `string`, e.g.,

```
t.string "email", default: "",  null: false
```

Comment: Thank you for your response! I actually have the comma in mine, I had copied that from someone else that had the same question rather than from my own code (stupid stupid stupid). My apologies. Edited to reflect this.

Answer (score 0):

You should not run the rake command from mysql console.

Open your terminal and run `rake db:migrate` from there. If you still face any issues - update the question.